Duct work mudded, but not actually attached
I was replacing some trim and have come across a weird situation with the duct work. It seems like they just mudded it into place and didn’t actually connect the pieces together. When I removed the old trim the mud just started to fall apart and the upper duct piece flexed apart. So now there is a pretty big gap in between the two pieces. There isn’t any sort of mating piece or lip it could be tucked into that I can feel in there. What’s the best way to close that gap? Do I even need to close it? Like I could probably just put more drywall mud or expanding foam in there to close it, but is that an acceptable repair?



Is this a return duct or a supply duct? Return ducts are sometimes (more in the past than present due to fire codes) pretty much "connect a duct to a studwall cavity and let it be the duct" (Or a joist cavity...)

It is a supply duct. The house is from the 1960s, so it sounds like that might be the case

I don't see any duct work.  I see an old style interior stucco over lath wall.
Unless you know for certain there is actual duct work in there somewhere, just mud over the stucco after coating the rusted lath with a rust inhibiter or convertor.

You don't see the inside of the duct in the first pic?

I don't see where the OP states that the duct pieces fell apart.  I believe the lath and stucco is unrelated to the ductwork.

There is definitely metal duct in there. I can feel it continue under the floor

If you can feel it, use some aluminum tape and tape the joints. The wall treatment had nothing to do with the duct work.

@RMDman you said "I don't see any duct work," when it's right there.

@Huseman, look at the bottom picture and tell me how one would be able to discern any duct work .  The upper pic just showed where a base board was and a big black rectangle.  I don't live in the OPs home...I couldn't tell that was an opening to a return duct.  Still the issue with a gap between 2 pieces is not apparent in either pic.   This is a case of "guess what's here."
